# How to update file path permanently

Tags: xml, winforms

In Windows form application I am reading an xml from default path to show the data in form. In case the file is not present I have given option to browse the file manually. What I want to give user an option to update the default path of the xml file to newly browsed location? Any suggestion how can I achieve this. Currently I have kept default path in a constant value which can not be updated.

I thought of keeping this xml path and any paths updated in future in an xml file. But I don't want to go with this option mere for storing file paths.

Comment: Use [settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)... that's what they're for.

Comment: @JoshPart: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx says settings persist for application session. But I want to make it save permanently so that when user next time open the application so default value will be the last browsed value. Is it possible to persist for lifetime?

Comment: It also states that `You can persist the changes to the settings between application sessions by calling the Save method.`

Answer (score 0):

You can save this value and any other settings you want in `app.config`. Use the `ConfigurationManager` class to read and write the settings like this:

```
using System.Configuration;

//To update the value of a setting:
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["my_key"] = "new_value";

//To create a new setting:
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add("another_key", "another_value");

//To read the value of a setting:
var may_setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your_key"];
```

Check this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Alternatively, you can save your settings in the Windows Reg.

Of course, you can also use your own XML or even text file (similar to the `INI` files) to save your settings. It all depends on your needs.